# What are the orgins of the terms "parse" in java?

Tags: java, string

In java I noticed there are methods associated with conversion of `strings` and those methods sometimes use the word "parse" in the name of the method. For example the static method,

```
static int parseInt(String str)
```

is used to convert a `string` into `int`. My question is this. Is "parse" short for another word? Is it just a random word or did it come from somewhere else in some other programming context in Java or anywhere else?

Comment: Did you try looking it up in a dictionary?

Comment: @StephenC I did but I was just wondering if it had a programming origin or if it was just chosen because of the latin root word Mechanicalfish posted.

Comment: If the dictionary didn't answer that, try an online one ...

Comment: I must admit that 'parse' is a poor choice of terminology for these methods. It is data conversion, not parsing.

Answer (score 5):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing):
Parsing or syntactic analysis is the process of analysing a string of symbols, either in natural language or in computer languages, according to the rules of a formal grammar. The term parsing comes from Latin pars (ōrātiōnis), meaning part (of speech).